# Handling Data From a TXT File When Opened In IOS WebView

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

**Background**

I am rewriting an `Android` application in `Swift`. The point of the app is that it loads a website in a `webView`, allows the user to login then gives them access to a link called, "Download Your Data".

**Problem**

Right now when the user clicks the link in IOS it opens a txt file in the view. So the whole txt file appears inside the view on the screen.

In Android it downloads the file and I can access it through a file system then `POST` the data to the server.

**Question**

Considering that the data appears in the screen and does not download or give me access to the file through a file system,

In what ways or how, can I access this file or data inside the file so I can post it to the server?

**Example Code**

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let viewUrl = URL(string: "https://www.example.com")
        let viewUrlRequest = URLRequest(url: viewUrl!)
        webView.load(viewUrlRequest)
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm looking for something similar, I think - have you checked out `UIDocumentInteractionController`?

Comment: I solved this give me a biIt and I'll show you.

Comment: Cool, looking forward!

Comment: Hey buddy sorry it took me so long to get back to you. I posted an answer in my question because it was so much to explain in a comment. I hope this helps you. Let me know if anything does not make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

The way I handled this was by sniffing the traffic of while the request was being made. Looking for the necessary headers and url endpoints then forming a query in Swift to take care of the file download. Once I got the data I was able to do whatever I wanted with it. In my situation I posted it to a server.

**Charles**

You can find [Charles here](https://www.charlesproxy.com/)

> Charles is an HTTP proxy / HTTP monitor / Reverse Proxy that enables a
>   developer to view all of the HTTP and SSL / HTTPS traffic between
>   their machine and the Internet. This includes requests, responses and
>   the HTTP headers (which contain the cookies and caching information).

You will need this to investigate the http request you need to make in order to obtain the data in your app. This way you can make the request pragmatically and control the flow of the app.

In my app I used javascript to simulate clicks and force the download. I had to attach the correct headers to my http request which I located using `Charles`.

**Explanation of Solution**

Here is an example using Swift and injecting javascript. This shows how to add the headers and make the http request. You will have to take the time to figure out what you need to change to make this work. But the logic is here.

In my case I had to log a user into the website, click a link that accepts terms and conditions and then click the link to download the data. If you just need to hit an endpoint then you will not need to make this as extensive as me. If you do need to simulate clicks then my code should help a lot.

**Example Code**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Downloader: NSObject {
    enum Step { case idle, login, agreeToTerms, download }


    var currentStep = Step.idle
    var uiwebview: UIWebView!
    var username: String = ""
    var password: String = ""
    var completion: ((Data?, Error?) -> Void)?

    static var downloader: Downloader!

    static func download(username: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (Data?, Error?) -> Void) {
        if self.downloader == nil { self.downloader = Downloader() }

        self.downloader.uiwebview = UIWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 480))
        self.downloader.uiwebview.scalesPageToFit = true
        self.downloader.uiwebview.delegate = self.downloader

        self.downloader.username = username
        self.downloader.password = password
        self.downloader.completion = completion

        let url = URL(string: "URL-END-POINT-HERE")!
        self.downloader.currentStep = .login
        self.downloader.uiwebview?.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url))
    }
}

extension Downloader: UIWebViewDelegate {
    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        if self.currentStep == .login, webView.request!.url?.absoluteString == "SOME-OTHER-URL-ACTION" {
            let script = "document.getElementById('signInNew:inputUserId').value = '\(self.username)'; document.getElementById('signInNew:inputPassword').value = '\(self.password)'; document.getElementById('signInNew:signin_login').click()"
            self.currentStep = .agreeToTerms
            webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: script)
        } else if self.currentStep == .agreeToTerms, webView.request!.url?.absoluteString == "https://www.nslds.ed.gov/npas/pub/disclaimer.htm" {
            self.currentStep = .download
            webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.getElementsByClassName('button signIn')[0].click()")
        } else if self.currentStep == .download, webView.request?.url?.absoluteString == "SOME-OTHER-URL-ACTION" {
            let url = URL(string: "SOME-OTHER-URL-ACTION")!
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            var headers = request.allHTTPHeaderFields ?? [:]

            if let cookies = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies(for: url) {
                for (key, value) in HTTPCookie.requestHeaderFields(with: cookies) { headers[key] = value }
            }
            // headers here - change these to the correct headers
            headers["Accept"] = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"
            headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip, deflate, sdch, br"
            headers["Accept-Language"] = "en-US,en;q=0.8"
            headers["Connection"] = "keep-alive"
            headers["Referer"] = "URL-REFERER-HERE-END-POINT"
            headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.1.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/14E8301"
            //headers["Referer"] = "URL-REFERER-HERE-END-POINT"
            request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
            request.httpShouldHandleCookies = false

            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
                self.completion?(data, error)
            }.resume()
        } else {
            print("URL mismatch: \(webView.request!.url!.absoluteString)")
            self.completion?(nil, NSError(domain: "Connection", code: 100, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Check username & password \nDownload sequence mismatch"]))
        }
    }
}
```